# how to adjust height for section table view

Tags: ios, tableview

i want ask how to adjust height section like this :

[image: header section original]

but if i click cell (detail) will be direct another viewcontroller, and back to this viewcontroller, view is seen like this :

[image: header section is covered by NavigationItem]

if you drag / scroll bottom, header section will show and if you release, it will bounce back covered by NavigationItem

any advice? thx before

Comment: What are your tableview's constraints?

Comment: what constraint? i just using add missing constraint for label

Comment: Your tableview's contsraints. Could you share your storyboard for us?(just this part is enough)

Comment: file storyboard? or screenshoot?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you:

```
 self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = YES;
 self.tableView.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
```